# Integrate ElasticSearch with MongoDB database

Tags: mongodb, express, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to implement search functionality in which my search will return documents which match the text typed in search bar

My MongoDB database is hosted on MongoLabs and I want ElasticSearch to search from a Collection that is available in this database.

I am using express and angular and I work on Windows,so please answer accordingly.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try [mongoosastic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoosastic). This plugin will index mongo models in elasticsearch.